# mongodb compare two arrays and return difference

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB collection as below

```
{
_id: 1
"probes": ["A", "B"],
"result": ["A", "B","C","D"],
}
```

I want to compare probes with result and create a new field called exception

```
{
_id: 1
"probes": ["A", "B"],
"result": ["A", "B","C","D"],
"exception" : ["C","D"]
}
```

if the exception field is already present, then it has to be overwritten.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            exception: {
                $setDifference: [ "$result", "$probes" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-cXiNs_amPT)